# Integrating a mailing list application with a social site

Tags: java, email, newsletter

I work on a social site, built using Java Spring. I reached the point where I want to notify my users on the latest happenings among their friends via email. Since I do not want to spam them every time when something happens, I actually want to send them an aggregated newsletter, perhaps every few hours or sth. The problems I currently have are the following:

1. The newsletter must be built automatically, literally, as events occur, they are collected in a queue, which is offloaded to the newsletter manager from time to time, which then handles laying them out in a nice format.
2. No matter what predefined design template I use, I will always end up with more or less unique newsletter (based on the events in a user's community)

How should I handle this gracefully. I have completely no experience with newsletter apps, but I do not want to code this functionality into my app. Even suggesting me a good app is a start?

P.S. I saw that mailchimp has a developer API. Will this help.

Answer (score 2):

MailChimp's servers and standard API are designed for one-to-many newsletters messages. It sounds like you are describing transactional one-to-one or one-off emails. They do have an API integration with Amazon's Simple Email Service where you can use MailChimp to track opens/clicks for an email while sending the email from Amazon's servers.

Branded "Simple Transactional Service", their API integration with Amazon's SES has documentation below.

intro: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/sts

apidocs: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/sts/rtfm

It also looks like they're rolling out a newer transactional API as well. In beta, this is probably going to be the best bet for longterm if not wanting to manage your own sending email servers.

http://mandrill.com/

http://mailchimp.com/about/press-releases/2011-10-27/

Essentially, it looks like you could manage marketing newsletters sent to the users (such as "these features have been added" using MailChimp's standard API while using Mandrill to send these aggregated "activity notification" emails.

Of course, you would have to code the dynamic content yourself within your app and pass it to the Mandrill/STS API for sending; but then MailChimp/Mandrill would be managing the technicalities of maintaining server reputation and enforcing CANSPAM compliance.

These transactional emails could be generated dynamically like a View within your app before passing the HTML to the API with instructions for sending it promptly.

As for a template, there are a ton of email-compliant templates lying around (in MailChimp, elsewhere) since writing email compliant HTML/CSS code is like going back to the 90s. (idk about legality, but it is possible to export a template straight from MailChimp and play with the source until the colors look slightly more unique.) ;-)

An example workflow:

1. event occurs
2. add event to user's Notifications relationship/collection (or invert the relationship and add users to event collection; whatever is the best design given the rest of the system)
3. if user-collection has size N, dump to email view and push to Mandrill/STS.

(oh yeah, and add settings to opt-out of these emails or they'll push that dreaded 'report spam' button, but that's probably obvious)

What else is obvious is that I use MailChimp with my internal software as well and am a huge fan of the company.